# React is removing dom before ReactCSSTransitionGroup animation finishes

Tags: reactjs

I a component that is supposed to swap out a line of text with a list of icons. I am trying to animate the departure of the text and the entry of the icons using ReactCSSTransitionGroup. The entry of the icons works fine but react kills the dom of the text before the animation can run. here's the render state of the component:

```
render () {
  return (
    <section className="SocialBlock" onMouseOver={this.showIcons} onMouseLeave={this.hideIcons}>
    {(() => {

      if (this.state.iconsAreVisible) {
        return (
          <div className={`socialAccounts`}>
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="socialIcons"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
          transitionAppear={true} >

          {socials.map((icon, index) => {
            return <div className={`icon icon-${index+1}`} key={index}><InlineSVG src={icon} /></div>
          })}
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          </div>
          )
      } else {
        return (
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="socialText"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
          transitionAppear={true} >
          <div key="12313"><h3>Check out the social stuff!</h3></div>
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>)
      }


    })()}

    </section>
    );
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. I can switch my animation classes to `appear` instead of `leave` and it works for the entry - but the departure is still abrupt.

Comment: Probably because you unmount the entire CSS transition group of the text on second render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this behavior because of the structure of your component.

When `(this.state.iconsvisible == false)`, then your entire second `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` will be unmounted, and will not be rendered.

And then it does not get the chance to do its `leave` transition.
Anything that needs to animate on leaving, should be inside the `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>`.

To fix, you could do this:

```
<section>
{
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  { if (this.state.iconsarevisible) {
      socials.map(...)
    }
  }
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>  
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  { if (!this.state.iconsarevisible) {
      <div>Check out social stuff</div>
    }
  }
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
}
</section>
```